# Using dplyr window functions to calculate percentiles

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a working solution but am looking for a cleaner, more readable solution that perhaps takes advantage of some of the newer dplyr window functions.

Using the mtcars dataset, if I want to look at the 25th, 50th, 75th percentiles and the mean and count of miles per gallon ("mpg") by the number of cylinders ("cyl"), I use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# load data
data("mtcars")

# Percentiles used in calculation
p <- c(.25,.5,.75)

# old dplyr solution 
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do(data.frame(p=p, stats=quantile(.$mpg, probs=p), 
                n = length(.$mpg), avg = mean(.$mpg))) %>%
  spread(p, stats) %>%
  select(1, 4:6, 3, 2)

# note: the select and spread statements are just to get the data into
#       the format in which I'd like to see it, but are not critical
```

Is there a way I can do this more cleanly with dplyr using some of the summary functions (n_tiles, percent_rank, etc.)?  By cleanly, I mean without the "do" statement.

Thank you

Comment: I should add that this code also uses the "tidyr" package, which is where the "spread" function comes from

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In `dplyr 1.0`, [`summarise`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-summarise/) can return multiple values, allowing the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%  
  summarise(quantile = scales::percent(c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)),
            mpg = quantile(mpg, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))
```

Or, you can avoid a separate line to name the quantiles by going with `enframe`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%  
  summarise(enframe(quantile(mpg, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)), "quantile", "mpg"))
```

> ```
>     cyl quantile   mpg
>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
> 1     4 25%       22.8
> 2     4 50%       26  
> 3     4 75%       30.4
> 4     6 25%       18.6
> 5     6 50%       19.7
> 6     6 75%       21  
> 7     8 25%       14.4
> 8     8 50%       15.2
> 9     8 75%       16.2
> ```

NOTE: As of `dplyr 1.1.0`, returning multiple rows per group with `summarise` is deprecated. Instead, use `reframe`, as in:

```
mtcars %>% 
 group_by(cyl) %>%  
 reframe(enframe(quantile(mpg, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)), "quantile", "mpg"))
```

---

**Answer for previous versions of `dplyr`**

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(x=list(enframe(quantile(mpg, probs=c(0.25,0.5,0.75)), "quantiles", "mpg"))) %>% 
  unnest(x)
```

> ```
>     cyl quantiles   mpg
> 1     4       25% 22.80
> 2     4       50% 26.00
> 3     4       75% 30.40
> 4     6       25% 18.65
> 5     6       50% 19.70
> 6     6       75% 21.00
> 7     8       25% 14.40
> 8     8       50% 15.20
> 9     8       75% 16.25
> ```

This can be turned into a more general function using tidyeval:

```
q_by_group = function(data, value.col, ..., probs=seq(0,1,0.25)) {

  groups=enquos(...)
  
  data %>% 
    group_by(!!!groups) %>% 
    summarise(x = list(enframe(quantile({{value.col}}, probs=probs), "quantiles", "mpg"))) %>% 
    unnest(x)
}

q_by_group(mtcars, mpg)
q_by_group(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
q_by_group(mtcars, mpg, cyl, vs, probs=c(0.5,0.75))
q_by_group(iris, Petal.Width, Species)
```

Comment: Thanks -- this is the answer I was looking for, which is that you can do it, but not in a seamless way with a single call to quantile (and that it is an open issue in dplyr development).

Comment: what if i want to summarise_all ?

Comment: This is so incredibly obscure, but I love it.

Comment: @OmarAbdEl-Naser e.g., use `summarise_all(.funs = function(x) list(enframe(quantile(x, probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75), na.rm = TRUE)))) %>% unnest`

Comment: @eipi10 How can you create a new variable in the same dataset with `quantile`? The downside of using it in summarize is that it collapses your dataset, when I usually want to calculate percentiles and simultaneously create a new variable while maintaining my dataset instead of collapsing. Is there an easier way than having to join it back to the original dataset?

Comment: For example, if you want to create a column with, say, deciles, you could do: `mtcars %>% mutate(mpg.decile = cut(mpg, breaks=quantile(mpg, probs=seq(0,1,0.1)), labels=10:1, include.lowest=TRUE))`.

Comment: If you want the percentile for each value in a column, you can use the `ecdf` function (empirical cumulative distribution function): `mtcars %>% mutate(mpg.pctile = ecdf(mpg)(mpg))`.

Answer (score 45):

If you're up for using `purrr::map`, you can do it like this!

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  nest(-cyl) %>%
  mutate(Quantiles = map(data, ~ quantile(.$mpg)),
         Quantiles = map(Quantiles, ~ bind_rows(.) %>% gather())) %>% 
  unnest(Quantiles)

#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>      cyl key   value
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1     6 0%     17.8
#>  2     6 25%    18.6
#>  3     6 50%    19.7
#>  4     6 75%    21  
#>  5     6 100%   21.4
#>  6     4 0%     21.4
#>  7     4 25%    22.8
#>  8     4 50%    26  
#>  9     4 75%    30.4
#> 10     4 100%   33.9
#> 11     8 0%     10.4
#> 12     8 25%    14.4
#> 13     8 50%    15.2
#> 14     8 75%    16.2
#> 15     8 100%   19.2
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

One nice thing about this approach is the output is tidy, one observation per row.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the cleanest approach.

Comment: The only thing I'd add is a "spread" at the end to make things tabular for presentation purposes, i.e. 
`%>% spread(names,x) `

Comment: Trying this now, I get stopped with `'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.`

Comment: Thanks @doconnor. I've updated my answer to not use broom anymore.

Comment: It's been bugging me that the `mutate` portion couldn't be done in one line with built-in `tidyverse` functionality, but I just realized the`enframe` function turns this into a one-liner: `mutate(Quantiles = map(data, ~ enframe(quantile(.$mpg), "quantile")))`.

Answer (score 18):

This is a `dplyr` approach that uses the `tidy()` function of the `broom` package, unfortunately it still requires `do()`, but it is a lot simpler.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    do( tidy(t(quantile(.$mpg))) )
```

which gives:

```
    cyl   X0.  X25.  X50.  X75. X100.
  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1     4  21.4 22.80  26.0 30.40  33.9
2     6  17.8 18.65  19.7 21.00  21.4
3     8  10.4 14.40  15.2 16.25  19.2
```

Note the use of `t()` since the `broom` package does not have a method for named numerics.

This is based on my [earlier answer for summary() here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263994/1328355).

Comment: If you also want to change column names you could even use `tidy::spread()` instead of `t()` and `stringr::str_c()`:  `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(tidy(quantile(.$mpg))) %>% mutate(names = stringr::str_c("Q", names)) %>% tidyr::spread(names, x)`. It is more verbose but gives you some freedom in adjustments.

Comment: tidy has been deprecated in favor of tibble::as_tibble()

Answer (score 12):

Not sure how to avoid `do()` in `dplyr`, but you can do this with `c()` and `as.list()` with `data.table` in a pretty straightforward manner:

```
require(data.table) 
as.data.table(mtcars)[, c(as.list(quantile(mpg, probs=p)), 
                        avg=mean(mpg), n=.N), by=cyl]
#    cyl   25%  50%   75%      avg  n
# 1:   6 18.65 19.7 21.00 19.74286  7
# 2:   4 22.80 26.0 30.40 26.66364 11
# 3:   8 14.40 15.2 16.25 15.10000 14
```

Replace `by` with `keyby` if you want them ordered by `cyl` column.

Comment: Good. I was aware of the `as.list` method in `[.data.table` and I tried it in `dplyr` but failed.

Comment: This is a nice solution -- I wish I could use it for my particular project but can't for reasons unrelated to the answer itself

Answer (score 8):

Answered many diffrent ways. dplyr distinct made the difference for what I wanted to do..

```
mtcars %>%
   select(cyl, mpg) %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   mutate( qnt_0   = quantile(mpg, probs= 0),
           qnt_25  = quantile(mpg, probs= 0.25),
           qnt_50  = quantile(mpg, probs= 0.5),
           qnt_75  = quantile(mpg, probs= 0.75),
           qnt_100 = quantile(mpg, probs= 1),
              mean = mean(mpg),
                sd = sd(mpg)
          ) %>%
   distinct(qnt_0 ,qnt_25 ,qnt_50 ,qnt_75 ,qnt_100 ,mean ,sd)
```

renders

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Groups:   cyl [3]
  qnt_0 qnt_25 qnt_50 qnt_75 qnt_100  mean    sd   cyl
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  17.8   18.6   19.7   21      21.4  19.7  1.45     6
2  21.4   22.8   26     30.4    33.9  26.7  4.51     4
3  10.4   14.4   15.2   16.2    19.2  15.1  2.56     8
```

Comment: Is there a reason to do `mutate()` then `distinct()` instead of `summarize()`?

Comment: The reason for the "distinct()" was to distill only one raw per "cyl".  There are always more than one way to slice  an orange. I'd probably use summarize today.

Answer (score 6):

This solution uses `dplyr` and `tidyr` only, lets you specify your quantiles in the `dplyr` chain, and takes advantage of `tidyr::crossing()` to "stack" multiple copies of the dataset prior to grouping and summarising.

```
diamonds %>%  # Initial data
  tidyr::crossing(pctile = 0:4/4) %>%  # Specify quantiles; crossing() is like expand.grid()
  dplyr::group_by(cut, pctile) %>%  # Indicate your grouping var, plus your quantile var
  dplyr::summarise(quantile_value = quantile(price, unique(pctile))) %>%  # unique() is needed
  dplyr::mutate(pctile = sprintf("%1.0f%%", pctile*100))  # Optional prettification
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 25 x 3
# Groups:   cut [5]
         cut pctile quantile_value
       <ord>  <chr>          <dbl>
 1      Fair     0%         337.00
 2      Fair    25%        2050.25
 3      Fair    50%        3282.00
 4      Fair    75%        5205.50
 5      Fair   100%       18574.00
 6      Good     0%         327.00
 7      Good    25%        1145.00
 8      Good    50%        3050.50
 9      Good    75%        5028.00
10      Good   100%       18788.00
11 Very Good     0%         336.00
12 Very Good    25%         912.00
13 Very Good    50%        2648.00
14 Very Good    75%        5372.75
15 Very Good   100%       18818.00
16   Premium     0%         326.00
17   Premium    25%        1046.00
18   Premium    50%        3185.00
19   Premium    75%        6296.00
20   Premium   100%       18823.00
21     Ideal     0%         326.00
22     Ideal    25%         878.00
23     Ideal    50%        1810.00
24     Ideal    75%        4678.50
25     Ideal   100%       18806.00
```

The `unique()` is necessary to let `dplyr::summarise()` know that you only want one value per group.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using a combination of `dplyr`, `purrr`, and `rlang`:

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# load data
data("mtcars")

# Percentiles used in calculation
p <- c(.25,.5,.75)

p_names <- paste0(p*100, "%")
p_funs <- map(p, ~partial(quantile, probs = .x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  set_names(nm = p_names)

# dplyr/purrr/rlang solution 
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(mpg), funs(!!!p_funs))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>     cyl `25%` `50%` `75%`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  22.8  26    30.4
#> 2     6  18.6  19.7  21  
#> 3     8  14.4  15.2  16.2


#Especially useful if you want to summarize more variables
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(mpg, drat), funs(!!!p_funs))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>     cyl `mpg_25%` `drat_25%` `mpg_50%` `drat_50%` `mpg_75%` `drat_75%`
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     4      22.8       3.81      26         4.08      30.4       4.16
#> 2     6      18.6       3.35      19.7       3.9       21         3.91
#> 3     8      14.4       3.07      15.2       3.12      16.2       3.22
```

Created on 2018-10-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

### Edit (2019-04-17):

As of `dplyr 0.8.0`, the `funs` function has been deprecated in favor of using `list` to pass the desired functions into scoped `dplyr` functions. As a result of this, the implementation above gets slightly more straightfoward. We no longer need to worry about unquoting the functions with the `!!!`. Please see the below `reprex`:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# load data
data("mtcars")

# Percentiles used in calculation
p <- c(.25,.5,.75)

p_names <- paste0(p*100, "%")
p_funs <- map(p, ~partial(quantile, probs = .x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  set_names(nm = p_names)

# dplyr/purrr/rlang solution 
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(mpg), p_funs)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>     cyl `25%` `50%` `75%`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  22.8  26    30.4
#> 2     6  18.6  19.7  21  
#> 3     8  14.4  15.2  16.2


#Especially useful if you want to summarize more variables
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(mpg, drat), p_funs)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>     cyl `mpg_25%` `drat_25%` `mpg_50%` `drat_50%` `mpg_75%` `drat_75%`
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     4      22.8       3.81      26         4.08      30.4       4.16
#> 2     6      18.6       3.35      19.7       3.9       21         3.91
#> 3     8      14.4       3.07      15.2       3.12      16.2       3.22
```

Created on 2019-04-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: that's very helpful. Don't know why this one did not have any upvotes yet.

Comment: Wrapping the three lines into one function makes it a bit neater, using `p_funs<-function() {etc}`. One needs to use `!!!p_funs()` in the `funs` call in this case

Comment: With the new version of `dplyr` the `funs` function is soft-deprecated and now you actually only need to call `p_funs` within `summarize_at`. Please see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly readable solution that uses `dplyr` and `purrr` to return quantiles in a tidy format:

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    do({x <- .$mpg
        map_dfr(.x = c(.25, .5, .75),
                .f = ~ data_frame(Quantile = .x,
                                  Value = quantile(x, probs = .x)))
       })
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl Quantile Value
  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     0.25 22.80
2     4     0.50 26.00
3     4     0.75 30.40
4     6     0.25 18.65
5     6     0.50 19.70
6     6     0.75 21.00
7     8     0.25 14.40
8     8     0.50 15.20
9     8     0.75 16.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to accomplish this, with unnest_wider/longer

```
    mtcars %>%
       group_by(cyl) %>%
       summarise(quants = list(quantile(mpg, probs = c(.01, .1, .25, .5, .75, .90,.99)))) %>%
       unnest_wider(quants)
```

And if you wanted to do it for multiple variables, you could gather before the grouping:

```
mtcars %>%
   gather(key = 'metric', value = 'value', -cyl) %>%
   group_by(cyl, metric) %>%
   summarise(quants = list(quantile(value, probs = c(.01, .1, .25, .5, .75, .90,.99)))) %>%
  unnest_wider(quants)
```

Answer (score 0):

`do()` is in fact the correct idiom, since it’s designed for group-wise transformations. Think of it as an `lapply()` that maps over groups of a data frame. (For such a specialized function, a generic name like “do”  is not ideal. But it’s probably too late to change it.)

Morally, within each `cyl` group, you want to apply `quantile()` to the `mpg` column:

```
library(dplyr)

p <- c(.2, .5, .75)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(quantile(.$mpg, p))

#> Error: Results 1, 2, 3 must be data frames, not numeric
```

Except that doesn’t work because `quantile()` doesn’t return a data frame; you must convert its output, explicitly. Since this alteration amounts to wrapping `quantile()` with a data frame, you can use the [gestalt](https://github.com/egnha/gestalt) function composition operator `%>>>%`:

```
library(gestalt)
library(tibble)

quantile_tbl <- quantile %>>>% enframe("quantile")

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(quantile_tbl(.$mpg, p))

#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl quantile value
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1     4 20%       22.8
#> 2     4 50%       26  
#> 3     4 75%       30.4
#> 4     6 20%       18.3
#> 5     6 50%       19.7
#> 6     6 75%       21  
#> 7     8 20%       13.9
#> 8     8 50%       15.2
#> 9     8 75%       16.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `q_summarise()` from my package timeplyr.

It's both tidy-based (using data-masking rules) and very fast as it uses
`collapse` and `data.table` under the hood.

```r
# To install, uncomment the below line
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")

library(tidyverse)
library(timeplyr)

mtcars %>%
  q_summarise(mpg, .by = cyl, probs = p)
#>    cyl   p25  p50   p75
#> 1:   4 22.80 26.0 30.40
#> 2:   6 18.65 19.7 21.00
#> 3:   8 14.40 15.2 16.25

mtcars %>%
  q_summarise(mpg, .by = cyl, probs = p, pivot = "long")
#>    cyl .quantile   mpg
#> 1:   4       p25 22.80
#> 2:   4       p50 26.00
#> 3:   4       p75 30.40
#> 4:   6       p25 18.65
#> 5:   6       p50 19.70
#> 6:   6       p75 21.00
#> 7:   8       p25 14.40
#> 8:   8       p50 15.20
#> 9:   8       p75 16.25

# Comparison when there are lots of groups

df <- tibble(g = sample.int(10^4, replace = TRUE),
                             x = rnorm(10^4))

bench::mark(timeplyr = q_summarise(df, x, .by = g,
                        pivot = "long", probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25)),
            dplyr = q_by_group(df, x, g, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25)),
            check = FALSE)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 timeplyr     27.7ms   31.4ms    29.7      2.06MB     5.95
#> 2 dplyr          1.5s     1.5s     0.665    5.33MB     5.99
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>