# using dplyr's do() with summary()

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I would like to be able to use `dplyr`'s split-apply-combine strategy to the apply the `summary()` command.

Take a simple data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(class = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                 value = c(100, 120, 800, 880))
```

Ideally we would do something like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  do(summary(.$value))
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `dplyr`'s `do()` only works with with input of the form `data.frame`.

The [broom package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=broom)'s `tidy()` function can be used to convert outputs of `summary()` to `data.frame`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  do( tidy(summary(.$value)) )
```

This gives:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
Groups: class [2]

   class minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum
  (fctr)   (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl)
1      A     100   105    110   110   115     120
2      B     800   820    840   840   860     880
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the SE version of `data_frame`, that is, `data_frame_` and perform:

```
df %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  do(data_frame_(summary(.$value)))
```

Alternatively, you can use `as.list()` wrapped by `data.frame()` with the argument `check.names = FALSE`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  do(data.frame(as.list(summary(.$value)), check.names = FALSE))
```

Both versions produce:

```
# Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
# Groups: class [2]
# 
#    class  Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu.  Max.
#   (fctr) (dbl)   (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl) (dbl)
# 1      A   100     105    110   110     115   120
# 2      B   800     820    840   840     860   880
```

Comment: Thanks, this output looks perfect. I've read about SE a bit but never quite understood it. Which package do these functions belong to? From the use of `_` it looks like one of @hadley. I also found a way to use `tidy()` from the broom package. See below.

Comment: `data_frame` and `data_frame_` come from `dplyr`. This answer deserves the checkmark as far as I'm concerned, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. And thank you for volunteering that, I changed it.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of `do` will change depending on whether you give it a named or unnamed argument. For unnamed arguments, it expects a data.frame for each group, which will be binded together. For named arguments it will make a row for each group, and put whatever the output is into a new variable with that name.

So in this case we it will complain for unnamed use (`summary` does not produce a data.frame) but the named use will work:

```
df %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  do(summaries = summary(.$value)) ->
  df2
```

Which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

   class                  summaries
  (fctr)                      (chr)
1      A <S3:summaryDefault, table>
2      B <S3:summaryDefault, table>
```

We can access a summary like this:

```
df2$summaries[[1]]
```

Giving:

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
100     105     110     110     115     120
```

Getting all of these as new columns for `df` can only be done by first converting the output to a data.frame, as can be seen in the other answers.

So the root of the problem here is that `summary` outputs a `table` instead of a data.frame.

Comment: thanks, this is great. Another way I just came across would be to use the `tidy()` function from the broom package. But naming it is a very simple way to avoid that.